# getline() from a textfile error

Tags: c++, text, getline

For a lab for school I am trying to get lines from a text file and display them.

My start:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <playlist.h>

using namespace std;

void readLine(vector<string> playlist);
int totalTime();
void displayData();

int main()
{
    vector<string> playlist;

    readLine(playlist);
    totalTime();
    displayData();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
void readLine(vector<string> playlist)
{
    string currentline;
    int i = 0;
    while (getline("Playlist.txt", currentline) && !empty(currentline))
    {
        getline("Playlist.txt", playlist[i]);
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
int totalTime() 
{

}
void displayData()
{

}
```

It seems that I am misusing the getline? The two "getline"s have error underlines saying:

> getline
>
> Error: no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the
>   argument list argument types are: (const char [13], std::string)

I don't know the cause of the error.

Comment: Surely the documentation for `getline` has a clue to the problem. What don't you understand?

Answer (score 5):

You aren't missing the `getline` function, you're using it wrong.

`getline` expects an `std::istream&` and a `std::string&`.  You need to open a `std::ifstream` to the file and pass this stream as the first parameter.

See here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Answer (score 3):

Modify the `readLine()` function like so, either pass in the `playlist` as a reference or return the `playlist` vector and move it into another vector, because unless you are doing something you excluded from your code the `playlist` vector would be lost

```
vector<string> readLine(vector<string> playlist)
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("Playlist.txt");
    if (!fin) { 
        cerr << "Could not open file Playlist.txt" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    string currentline;
    int i = 0;
    while (getline(fin, currentline) && !empty(currentline))
    {
        getline(fin, playlist[i]);
        i = i + 1;
    }

    return playlist;
}
```

This is because the declaration of version of getline you are trying to look looks like so

```
istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str);
```

This expects a reference to an `istream` object as the first type and if you see the inheritance hierarchy here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/?kw=ifstream you will see that an object of type `ifstream` inherits from `istream`

NOTE : As pointed out in the comments below what you are doing does not seem to be right. I do not know how I missed this. But what you are doing seems to be wrong. If your intention is to make the `playlist` vector store all non empty lines in the text file you should have a loop like so

```
string temp;
while (getline(fin, temp)) {
    if (!temp.empty()) {
        lines.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

Additionally want to check for spaces you would need to program that logic in as well

Comment: I don't know if you should point out that the original code reads a line, and if it isn't empty, discards it, saving the next line into the playlist, regardless of whether it is empty or not (and ignoring EOF too).  This is probably not the intended design.  Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: Additionally, the method above doesn't actually do anything in practice because nothing is done with `playlist` once the method completes.